# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined for jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I'm trying to add new rule to jquery validation for date validation. Here is m code.

Form

```
<form class="form-edit-add find_crime" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type='text' class="form-control start_date" name ="start_date" id="start_date"/>
   <input type='text' class="form-control end_date" name ="end_date" id="end_date"/>
</form>
```

my jquery

```
$(function(){
            $.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
                function(value, element, params) {

                    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
                        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
                    }

                    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
                        || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
                },'Must be greater than {0}.');

            $("#end_date").rules('add', { greaterThan: "#start_date" });

            $(".find_crime").validate({
                    rules: {
                        EndDate: { greaterThan: "#start_date" }
                    }
            });

 });
```

But I'm getting this error instead,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/), you can only call `.rules()` method AFTER `.validate()` has been called.

Comment: You're also attaching `.validate()` to a class, which seems to imply you have more than one form you're trying to validate.  You cannot do this.  The method was designed to only attach to a single `form` element, so only *the first* `form` on the page matching that class will be validated.  The workaround here is to also incorporate an `.each()` so you can attach `.validate()` to all forms with that class.   Based on these two issues alone, I think you should go read the documentation more thoroughly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e48yctwq/

Comment: Why are you using the `.rules()` method in first place?  `EndDate` inside the `.validate()` method is nonsense since it does not match any element names.   See:  https://jsfiddle.net/jd4vqms8/